# what is -eq purpose

Tags: command-line, bash

i use -eq at my branching bash codes but it wont work well is it -eq has a same role == in java because i use it wih the same way

```
. confirm.sh
confirm
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
        echo “Jawaban YES OK” 
elif [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
        echo “Jawaban NO” 
elif [ $? -eq 2 ]
then
        echo “Jawaban CONTINUE
fi
```

”

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBA1Z.png)

when the $? = 2 it should be continue but why it still NO

Comment: What are `confirm.sh` and `confirm`? Do they return the exit status you expect? Use `bash -x` to run the script to see debug output.

Answer (score 2):

In a comparison like `test`, `[` or `[[`, `-eq` is the equals-to operator for arithmetic expressions.

If the comparison holds, then the test returns 0.

See the [Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22473).

---

Your code does not work, because `$?` refers to the last exit status. You have to save it before processing it any further:

```
confirm
ret=$?
if [ $ret -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Jawaban YES OK"
elif [ $ret -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "Jawaban NO"
elif [ $ret -eq 2 ]
then
    echo "Jawaban CONTINUE"
fi
```

You can also use `case` here:

```
confirm
ret=$?
case $ret in
  0) echo "Jawaban YES OK" ;;
  1) echo "Jawaban NO" ;;
  2) echo "Jawaban CONTINUE" ;;
esac
```